# Get a column data from one table and update it to another column from another table - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `tbl_Invoice` and `tbl_tax`.

```
tbl_invoice

id | amount | tax
------------------
01 | 150.00 | 2.5
02 | 250.00 | 3.2
03 | 350.00 | 1.5

tbl_tax

id | inv_id | tax
-----------------
01 | 01     | 2.6
02 | 02     | 5.2
02 | 03     | 6.2
```

I have to update the `tbl_Invoice` `tax` column with the `tbl_tax` `tax` column, end results should be like

```
tbl_invoice

id | amount | tax
------------------
01 | 150.00 | 2.6
02 | 250.00 | 5.2
03 | 350.00 | 6.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
UPDATE tbl_invoice Inv
LEFT JOIN tbl_tax Tax ON Inv.id = Tax.inv_id 
SET Inv.tax = Tax.tax
```

Reference [MySQL UPDATE JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Comment: Thank you, Was helful

Answer (score 1):

To update such data use a subquery and fetch the `tax` from you `tbl_tax` table taking the common `inv_id` from `tbl_tax` and `id` from `tbl_invoice` fields.

```
update 
tbl_invoice ti 
set 
ti.tax=(select tt.tax from tbl_tax tt where tt.inv_id=ti.id)
```

Or you can use a join to update your records:

```
UPDATE tbl_invoice ti
INNER JOIN `tbl_tax` tt ON  tt.`inv_id`=ti.`id`
SET ti.`tax`=tt.`tax`
```